# Harry Potter fanfic where Harry is a magical genius

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I remember Harry condensing cloud and using them as a way to move around the castle. At one point when he’s experimenting with his magic he blasts a hole in the dungeon wall. Pretty sure I read it on Archive of Our Own. He starts manipulating water at first then escalates onto other things. I’m fairly sure it was a pretty long (novel length) and well written fic but somehow I don’t really remember anything about the actual plot other than him managing to shock everyone with his new discoveries of magic. There is either no relationship or it’s slash but I think the story mainly focuses on his magic and not romance. I’m pretty sure he was in Gryffindor, and I can’t really remember any of his other experiments or discoveries except maybe at one point he managed to turn wood into gold?

Comment: This is quite brief at the moment, could you [edit] in anything else you may remember? For example, when did you read this? Where did you read this? Any more plot elements? See [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11922/58193) for details.

Comment: Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality http://www.hpmor.com

Comment: HPMOR has a rational Harry, not a genius Harry.

Comment: can you give us a little more info? is it novel length (60k-ish words or more)? When did you read this? Was he in Ravenclaw? Do you remember any other discoveries he made?

Comment: @NeoDarwin - That might be what the author *meant* to write.

Comment: No it’s not the methods of rationality I’ve read it before but unfortunately it’s not that one. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @Sensoray it says that he is in Gryffindor . . . most likely?

Comment: @Silvermidnight if you check my comment date and their edit date, you'll see they added that info a day after my comment. prob after reading my comment.

Comment: @Sensoray Sorry, I didn't check the edits before I commented.

Comment: @Silvermidnight no worries ^-^